# Gamma function plot in Python

Tags: python, plot, scipy, matplotlib

So I'd like to plot simple gamma function, but I have some problems. My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: cp1250 -*-
#import math
from scipy.special import *
#from scitools.std import *
from pylab import *

def f1(x):
    return gamma(x)


x = linspace(-6, 6, 512)
y1 = f1(x)

# Matlab-style syntax:
plot(x, y1)

xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
legend(r'$\Gamma(x)$')
grid(True)

show()
```

I tried importing the gamma function from math, and from scipy.special but I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:/faxstuff/3.godina/kvantna/plotgamma.py", line 13, in  y1 = f1(x) File "D:/faxstuff/3.godina/kvantna/plotgamma.py", line 9, in f1 return gamma(x) File "mtrand.pyx", line 1599, in mtrand.RandomState.gamma (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:8389) ValueError: shape <= 0

How to do it? This should be easy, but I seem to fail :(

Comment: Please post the exact error messages.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/faxstuff/3.godina/kvantna/plotgamma.py", line 13, in <module>
    y1 = f1(x)
  File "D:/faxstuff/3.godina/kvantna/plotgamma.py", line 9, in f1
    return gamma(x)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1599, in mtrand.RandomState.gamma (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:8389)
ValueError: shape <= 0`

Comment: This is a good example of why `import *` is not recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the modules (pylab, I think) is shadowing the gamma function by the gamma random variable function.  This works, but I had to turn off the call to legend (I'm not sure why, yet).

```
from scipy.special import gamma as Gamma
#from scitools.std import *
from pylab import *

def f1(x):
    return Gamma(x)


x = linspace(-6, 6, 512)
y1 = f1(x)
gca().set_autoscale_on(False)

# Matlab-style syntax:
plot(x, y1)

xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
# legend(r'$\Gamma(x)$')
axis([-6, 6, -100, 100])
grid(True)

show()
```

Comment: Needed to change it to: legend([r'$\Gamma(x)$'])

Comment: This is a perfect illustration of why "from foo import *" is not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in a Sage notebook:

```
# Simple example demonstrating how to interact with matplotlib directly.
# Comment plt.clf() to get the plots overlay in each update.

from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

@interact
def plot_gamma(a=(1,(1,10)), loc=(0,(0,10)), scale=(1,(1,10))):
    rv = stats.gamma(a, loc, scale)
    x = np.linspace(-1,20,1000)
    plt.plot(x,rv.pdf(x))
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig('plt.png')
    plt.clf()
```